# How to hide entire table row<tr> in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very big table of data. For reference I'm printing below the HTML of only two records:

```
<table width="100%" class="base-table tbl-practice" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr class="evenRow">
        <th width="33%" style="text-align:center;" class="question-id">Que ID</th>
        <th width="33%" style="text-align:center;" class="question-id">Matching Que IDs</th>
        <th width="33%" style="text-align:center;" class="question-id">Percentage(%)</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="oddRow">
        <td class="question-id" align="center" valign="top">
            <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=51550,51545#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE51550</a>
        </td>
        <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">
            <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=51550,51545#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE51545</a>              
            <a href="#deletePopContent" class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" delhref="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=delete&question_id=51545&subject_id=2&topic_id=464" title="Delete question"> Delete</a>              
        </td>
        <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">
            90.84<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oddRow">
        <td class="question-id" align="center" valign="top">
            <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=51589,51393#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE51589</a>    
        </td>
        <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">
            <a href="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_ids=51589,51393#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE51393</a>              
            <a href="#deletePopContent" class="c-icn c-remove delete_question" delhref="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/match_question.php?op=delete&question_id=51393&subject_id=2&topic_id=464" title="Delete question"> Delete</a>              
        </td>
        <td class="question" align="center" valign="top">
            91.80<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now If I want to hide the respective entire row when user clicks on the Delete icon for that row, how should I achieve this with jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the first matching parent

```
$('.delete_question').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    // any other code, e.g. some ajax here
});
```

You may also want to prevent the default click event (which is set to go to #deletePopContent)

```
$('.delete_question').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    // any other code, e.g. some ajax here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to delete the record by AJAX, the AJAX coe is working fine for me. I want one suggestion from you. hide could be a better option or any other like fadein or fade out. Can you help me in this ?

Comment: Replace `.hide();` with `.fadeOut();` I suspect you hadn't even tried.

Comment: Is the below code OK:
var $ele = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
$ele.fadeOut().remove();

Comment: No you're setting `$ele` to an ID and trying to execute jQuery on a string. You code PHP right? `$(this)` is a jQuery object, see it as a class, `.attr('id')` returns a string. Can you do this where `$ele ='SomeText';`: `$ele->someFunction();`? Nope. Clue: `$(this).closest('tr')` is a jQuery object.

Comment: But `$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut().remove();` will just remove. You will have to use `.fadeOut()`'s callback to make it wait for the fade to complete. That's where `.remove()` belongs. Please read the docs PHPLover. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(".delete_question").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').hide();
})
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tH9nc/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".delete_question").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
});
```

this will be helpful in nested tables also.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I have been working on for a project.

**Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/jDNy4/

When the remove button is clicked, an inline confirmation is required. If confirmed the tr is removed.

HTML

```
<table> 
<thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Current</th> 
        <th>2013</th> 
        <th>2012</th> 
        <th>2011</th> 
        <th>2010</th> 
        <th>2009</th> 
        <th>Budget</th> 
        <th>Proposed</th> 
        <th></th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 

<tbody> 
    <tr> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
        <td><input type="text" /></td> 
    </tr> 

</tbody> 

<tfoot> 
    <tr><td><a href="#" class="add">Add Row</a></td></tr> 
</tfoot> 
</table>
```

Javascript (jQuery 1.10.1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".add").click(function(){ 
$("tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td><td class="removeSelection"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>'); 
}); 

$("tbody").on('click','.remove',function(){ 
    $(this).parent().append( $( '<div class="confirmation"><a href="#" class="removeConfirm">Yes</a><a href="#" class="removeCancel">No</a></div>')) 
    $(this).remove(); 
}); 

$("tbody").on('click','.removeConfirm',function(){ 
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove(); 
}); 

$("tbody").on('click','.removeCancel',function(){ 
    $(this).parent().parent().append('<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>'); 
    $(this).parent().remove(); 
}); 
}); 

$(document).ready(function() { 
var form = $('#ajax'); // contact form 

// form submit event 
$(".text").blur(function(){ 

$.ajax({ 

  type: 'POST', // form submit method get/post 
  dataType: 'html', // request type html/json/xml 
  data: form.serialize(), // serialize form data  
  success: function(data) { 
    url: 'functions.php'; // form action url 
  }, 
  error: function(e) { 
    console.log(e) 
  } 
}); 
}); 
});
```